# How to repair a kitchen cabinet face that fell off?

Tags: cabinets

the front of the cabinet is broken. Looks like there is a rubbery-plastic piece at the back which is meant to hold the screws at the back of the cabinet face in place.

What is this piece called?

[image]

Can I fix this ?

Is there a better way to put this back together ?

[image]

Here is how the screws are placed into the back of the cabinet-face
[image]

Comment: There are many false drawer clips available.  Probably the easiest is this type: https://quikdrawers.com/economy-false-drawer-front-clip You just rotate them diagonally so that they'll fit through the opening, then reach up and rotate them vertical so that the clips grab the cabinet frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can fix this.

Reinstall with a couple new *L* brackets. Perhaps one at each corner.

I would pre-drill the holes to prevent cracking and splitting and reattach, should be fairly simple.

First, attach them to the face frame of the cabinet and then to the back of the false front. You might have someone give you a hand holding it in place if needed.

Any hardware store should have these and some even come with the required screws. You'll want some 1/2" L brackets.

[image: L bracket]

Comment: Complete noob here. L brackets go in the corner of the plank or the opening ?

Comment: Like this one ? https://www.lowes.com/pd/Simpson-Strong-Tie-2-in-14-Gauge-Wood-to-Wood-Black-Triple-Zinc-Angle/1002739006

Comment: They would attach the false front to the face frame of the cabinet. You'll want a 1/2" L bracket. Lowes, Home Depot or even Ace Hardware should carry them. Any hardware store really.